# Why is this program crashing and returning large values?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a decimal to binary converter but its crashing the program. Could anyone please help

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

char *decToBin(unsigned long,int i=0);

int main()
{
    unsigned long n;
    cout<<"Enter number: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<decToBin(n)<<endl;
};

char *decToBin(unsigned long dec, int i)
{
    if(dec==1)
    {
        return "1";
    }
    char *bin=new char[sizeof(dec)*8+1];
 
    bin=strcat(decToBin((unsigned long)(dec/2),i+1),((dec%2==1)?"1":"0"));
    return bin;
}
```

It only works for `1` and for `2` it exits after `4.326` seconds and returns a return value `3221225477`. I don't know the meaning of this return value. I didn't mention any return value.

Also I'm instructed to use char arrays as strings

I think the function creates an infinite loop and i don't know a way to fix this.

Comment: That is not a whole program (you should post a [mcve]), so it's hard to say for sure, but if you are writing in C++, why are you not using `std::string`?

Comment: If this is actually supposed to be C++, use `std::string` ... also, consider what happens in your code when `dec` is 0

Comment: Your code leaks memory on each recursive call. I don't think this is the cause of a crash however.

Comment: `strcat` does not take the two arguments and magically appends them together. Rather, it appends the second argument to the first. What do you think is it to what the penultimate recursive invocation appends?

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.  It should tell you that you're trying to convert a string literal to an integer, which should indicate to you that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: There is actually only one warning and it tells that assigning strings to char array is depreciated

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/amp/

Comment: At the end of main main calls itself - see `main();` . Fix this issue and see what happens

Comment: There is no error due to `main();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below solution works up to 64 bit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    unsigned long n;
    std::cout << "Enter n:"; 
    std::cin >> n;
    if(0 == n) {
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::string binary = std::bitset<64>(n).to_string(); 
        std::cout<< binary.erase(0, binary.find_first_not_of('0')) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Example:**

```
dec2bin
Enter n:10
1010
```